# Кнопки поделиться от Яндекс для темы "Newspaper"

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день, друзья! Подскажите, есть ли какая-то особенность вставки кода сервиса "Яндекс.Поделиться", если применена в WordPress тема «Newspaper»? Что только не делал, не появляются кнопки. Помогите, пожалуйста, советом!

Comment: Покажите, что вы делали.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, речь идет об этой теме: https://themeforest.net/item/newspaper/5489609

Она использует Visual Composer. Вопрос, видимо, в том, как вставить код на страницу.

В Visual Composer на странице в нужном месте создайте блок html и в него вставьте код от Яндекс. Например:

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="collections,vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir"></div>
```

Пример страницы на моем тестовом сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/so641492/